# Where do I get a Paypal client id

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using the Paypal core SDK, rest API SDK for .net, as well as the adaptive payments SDK for .net all from the nuget package gallery in Visual Studio
For the adaptive payments credentials it asks for apiPassword, apisigniture, apiUsername and appid, that I can get from my Paypal account.
But with the rest SDK it uses a ClientId and ClientSecret. Where do I get these?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get your REST API Credentials here, Create Application and click the App name: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps